# Use curl to POST files on a two stages form - endomondo

Tags: forms, bash, file, post, curl

I'm trying to build a simple bash script to automatically upload .gpx file to endomondo from my home made "smartskateboard" using a raspberry.

**The steps to do this using a browser are :**

-Login on the website (and browse to the right place)

-Select a local file and post it. (the file is uploaded and parsed by the server)

-Validate the track and chose the sport.

*Here are some pictures* :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/aH1Yr.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jQVXM.png

I tried to use chrome dev tools and this is what I'v done yet.

I have managed to get the curl command to post a message :

```
curl 'https://www.endomondo.com/rest/v1/users/12598/feeds/' -H 'Pragma: no-cache' -H 'Origin: https://www.endomondo.com' -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate' -H 'X-CSRF-TOKEN: rd7g3v4jn7qb3tn850tadctgku' -H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,fr-FR;q=0.6,fr;q=0.4' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 7_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/537.51.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/7.0 Mobile/11A465 Safari/9537.53' -H 'Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8' -H 'Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*' -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' -H 'Referer: https://www.endomondo.com/home' -H 'Cookie: CSRF_TOKEN=rd7g3v4jn7qb3tn850tadctgku; EndomondoApplication_AUTO=; EndomondoApplication_AUTH="440BDF49EEB9D76EURIPamw77KUpPuQyzORKeykOJHruw8sKNRBWWA0HJ7BP6kfWNLgIy0ZrtapJam0G7F4xt7lZB7M%2FGp7aHoGLRcuXFnNE2UqIonAMHmNL6Nc%3D"; EndomondoApplication_USER="test%40test.test"; JSESSIONID=D44DF5952D9FB9ECB5770809674604BC; AWSELB=13FDC17D1C2B68745BCB41EBB6BDDC3DB8274D93D6BFB2FED334D90D6839B6C1C83CB494F784DFC9E02CB65D818CE77DB9BD0EC99020A8445EE98B4DBDFCA6E4A764395BA73DF1CBDA0BA244DD4CE2E654387EB981; __utma=162144232.146159703.1442243029.1451137760.1451149929.4; __utmb=162144232.9.10.1451149929; __utmc=162144232; __utmz=162144232.1442243029.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); USER_TOKEN=23EEE323B7AEA408yrCg5GoWVwn5pzcXtsVfJop8VgkqdNw9y6XCU1hTgcylJixgbmFwGy8k7IUp25N2CeS0aSn0B9R0B5KIcbwPK5HhL5znQwSCTQR%2FcV4xHZ8%3D; _dc_gtm_UA-273418-98=1; _gat=1; acceptCookies=1; _ga=GA1.2.146159703.1442243029' -H 'Connection: keep-alive' --data-binary '{"message":"I love sports and I dont care who know.","picture_keys":[]}' --compressed
```

Or, easier to see :

```
curl
'https://www.endomondo.com/rest/v1/users/12598/feeds/' -H
'Pragma: no-cache' -H
'Origin: https://www.endomondo.com' -H
'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate' -H
'X-CSRF-TOKEN: rd7g3v4jn7qb3tn850tadctgku' -H
'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,fr-FR;q=0.6,fr;q=0.4' -H
'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 7_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/537.51.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/7.0 Mobile/11A465 Safari/9537.53' -H
'Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8' -H
'Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*' -H
'Cache-Control: no-cache' -H
'Referer: https://www.endomondo.com/home' -H
'Cookie: CSRF_TOKEN=rd7g3v4jn7qb3tn850tadctgku; EndomondoApplication_AUTO=; EndomondoApplication_AUTH="440BDF49EEB9D76EURIPamw77KUpPuQyzORKeykOJHruw8sKNRBWWA0HJ7BP6kfWNLgIy0ZrtapJam0G7F4xt7lZB7M%2FGp7aHoGLRcuXFnNE2UqIonAMHmNL6Nc%3D"; EndomondoApplication_USER="test%40test.test"; JSESSIONID=D44DF5952D9FB9ECB5770809674604BC; AWSELB=13FDC17D1C2B68745BCB41EBB6BDDC3DB8274D93D6BFB2FED334D90D6839B6C1C83CB494F784DFC9E02CB65D818CE77DB9BD0EC99020A8445EE98B4DBDFCA6E4A764395BA73DF1CBDA0BA244DD4CE2E654387EB981; __utma=162144232.146159703.1442243029.1451137760.1451149929.4; __utmb=162144232.9.10.1451149929; __utmc=162144232; __utmz=162144232.1442243029.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); USER_TOKEN=23EEE323B7AEA408yrCg5GoWVwn5pzcXtsVfJop8VgkqdNw9y6XCU1hTgcylJixgbmFwGy8k7IUp25N2CeS0aSn0B9R0B5KIcbwPK5HhL5znQwSCTQR%2FcV4xHZ8%3D; _dc_gtm_UA-273418-98=1; _gat=1; acceptCookies=1; _ga=GA1.2.146159703.1442243029' -H
'Connection: keep-alive' --data-binary
'{"message":"I love sports and I dont care who know.","picture_keys":[]}' --compressed
```

But when I try to use the same "copy to cURL" technique to upload a gpx this is what I get :

```
curl 'https://www.endomondo.com/?x=0vBK0C*OVDu7aPYFZkE-CVgVIAFbs93VmWFtfCp7PaWi1ZSVu574S9sV8PL-3zjJUvnwjalxBcDaHd*-JuZnu52USOr5snwbRLbnzcTIw1AXlA-F028Z-Xs-0k5SWzAWYCg3I-wtaU3iwIxLLlrHgzW4j28xUw0QNh0zDH4z*Js&random=0.6610315972939134' -H 'Pragma: no-cache' -H 'Origin: https://www.endomondo.com' -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate' -H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,fr-FR;q=0.6,fr;q=0.4' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU iPhone OS 4_2_1 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/533.17.9 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.0.2 Mobile/8C148 Safari/6533.18.5' -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' -H 'Accept: text/xml' -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' -H 'Referer: https://www.endomondo.com/?x=-Ut4ofqQrclJ*V-2TTUglw' -H 'Cookie: CSRF_TOKEN=rd7g3v4jn7qb3tn850tadctgku; __utmt=1; _dc_gtm_UA-273418-98=1; _gat=1; EndomondoApplication_AUTO=; EndomondoApplication_AUTH="440BDF49EEB9D76EURIPamw77KUpPuQyzORKeykOJHruw8sKNRBWWA0HJ7BP6kfWNLgIy0ZrtapJam0G7F4xt7lZB7M%2FGp7aHoGLRcuXFnNE2UqIonAMHmNL6Nc%3D"; EndomondoApplication_USER="test%40test.test"; JSESSIONID=D44DF5952D9FB9ECB5770809674604BC; USER_TOKEN=4E6208A8CF58143F9JU58ueFMl0S5AJJhA8kgpfKDUL50Siopic6W7lYJlfi8BVhAr0s8LCDSyHNXNGXGMFfFpaxkpf0p8Voa9OIjSFxhWLuAHzq35QK7WQoX94%3D; AWSELB=13FDC17D1C2B68745BCB41EBB6BDDC3DB8274D93D6BFB2FED334D90D6839B6C1C83CB494F784DFC9E02CB65D818CE77DB9BD0EC99020A8445EE98B4DBDFCA6E4A764395BA73DF1CBDA0BA244DD4CE2E654387EB981; acceptCookies=1; _ga=GA1.2.146159703.1442243029; __utma=162144232.146159703.1442243029.1451137760.1451149929.4; __utmb=162144232.7.10.1451149929; __utmc=162144232; __utmz=162144232.1442243029.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none)' -H 'Connection: keep-alive' -H 'Wicket-Ajax: true' --data 'id40_hf_0=&csrftoken=rd7g3v4jn7qb3tn850tadctgku&workoutRow%3A0%3Amark=on&workoutRow%3A0%3Asport=89&reviewSumbit=1' --compressed
```

Or :

```
curl    '
https://www.endomondo.com/?x=0vBK0C*OVDu7aPYFZkE-CVgVIAFbs93VmWFtfCp7PaWi1ZSVu574S9sV8PL-3zjJUvnwjalxBcDaHd*-JuZnu52USOr5snwbRLbnzcTIw1AXlA-F028Z-Xs-0k5SWzAWYCg3I-wtaU3iwIxLLlrHgzW4j28xUw0QNh0zDH4z*Js&random=0.6610315972939134' -H    '
Pragma: no-cache' -H    '
Origin: https://www.endomondo.com' -H    '
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate' -H    '
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,fr-FR;q=0.6,fr;q=0.4' -H    '
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU iPhone OS 4_2_1 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/533.17.9 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.0.2 Mobile/8C148 Safari/6533.18.5' -H    '
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' -H    '
Accept: text/xml' -H    '
Cache-Control: no-cache' -H    '
Referer: https://www.endomondo.com/?x=-Ut4ofqQrclJ*V-2TTUglw' -H    '
Cookie: CSRF_TOKEN=rd7g3v4jn7qb3tn850tadctgku; __utmt=1; _dc_gtm_UA-273418-98=1; _gat=1; EndomondoApplication_AUTO=; EndomondoApplication_AUTH="440BDF49EEB9D76EURIPamw77KUpPuQyzORKeykOJHruw8sKNRBWWA0HJ7BP6kfWNLgIy0ZrtapJam0G7F4xt7lZB7M%2FGp7aHoGLRcuXFnNE2UqIonAMHmNL6Nc%3D"; EndomondoApplication_USER="test%40test.test"; JSESSIONID=D44DF5952D9FB9ECB5770809674604BC; USER_TOKEN=4E6208A8CF58143F9JU58ueFMl0S5AJJhA8kgpfKDUL50Siopic6W7lYJlfi8BVhAr0s8LCDSyHNXNGXGMFfFpaxkpf0p8Voa9OIjSFxhWLuAHzq35QK7WQoX94%3D; AWSELB=13FDC17D1C2B68745BCB41EBB6BDDC3DB8274D93D6BFB2FED334D90D6839B6C1C83CB494F784DFC9E02CB65D818CE77DB9BD0EC99020A8445EE98B4DBDFCA6E4A764395BA73DF1CBDA0BA244DD4CE2E654387EB981; acceptCookies=1; _ga=GA1.2.146159703.1442243029; __utma=162144232.146159703.1442243029.1451137760.1451149929.4; __utmb=162144232.7.10.1451149929; __utmc=162144232; __utmz=162144232.1442243029.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none)' -H    '
Connection: keep-alive' -H    '
Wicket-Ajax: true' --data    '
id40_hf_0=&csrftoken=rd7g3v4jn7qb3tn850tadctgku&workoutRow%3A0%3Amark=on&workoutRow%3A0%3Asport=89&reviewSumbit=1' --compressed
```

I get : 
         `<ajax-response><redirect><![CDATA[error]]></redirect></ajax-response>`

So I didn't even been able to try to submit it with the second command :

```
curl 'https://www.endomondo.com/?x=WlHAHVtjhk33-6IZe8pKNMcha8tKpVMtc7*LCDzjZIEH14OF2*ZrTz5U6XsxRTk3xhNTap*KHozta0ZwGX4renCl4kla788HolvOCWj8Yz9gkvwj2Yngw-hgnzScvIqHiZAZFeNpfszko*MwYqk2W2GbbT2zy9AALpIO4IAb1lw&random=0.6173482222948223' -H 'Pragma: no-cache' -H 'Origin: https://www.endomondo.com' -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate' -H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,fr-FR;q=0.6,fr;q=0.4' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 7_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/537.51.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/7.0 Mobile/11A465 Safari/9537.53' -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' -H 'Accept: text/xml' -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' -H 'Referer: https://www.endomondo.com/?x=C-bb6EzoU1JGg3brORVo4w' -H 'Cookie: CSRF_TOKEN=rd7g3v4jn7qb3tn850tadctgku; EndomondoApplication_AUTO=; EndomondoApplication_AUTH="440BDF49EEB9D76EURIPamw77KUpPuQyzORKeykOJHruw8sKNRBWWA0HJ7BP6kfWNLgIy0ZrtapJam0G7F4xt7lZB7M%2FGp7aHoGLRcuXFnNE2UqIonAMHmNL6Nc%3D"; EndomondoApplication_USER="test%40test.test"; JSESSIONID=D44DF5952D9FB9ECB5770809674604BC; AWSELB=13FDC17D1C2B68745BCB41EBB6BDDC3DB8274D93D6BFB2FED334D90D6839B6C1C83CB494F784DFC9E02CB65D818CE77DB9BD0EC99020A8445EE98B4DBDFCA6E4A764395BA73DF1CBDA0BA244DD4CE2E654387EB981; acceptCookies=1; _ga=GA1.2.146159703.1442243029; __utma=162144232.146159703.1442243029.1451137760.1451149929.4; __utmb=162144232.9.10.1451149929; __utmc=162144232; __utmz=162144232.1442243029.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); USER_TOKEN=23EEE323B7AEA408yrCg5GoWVwn5pzcXtsVfJop8VgkqdNw9y6XCU1hTgcylJixgbmFwGy8k7IUp25N2CeS0aSn0B9R0B5KIcbwPK5HhL5znQwSCTQR%2FcV4xHZ8%3D' -H 'Connection: keep-alive' -H 'Wicket-Ajax: true' --data 'id56_hf_0=&csrftoken=rd7g3v4jn7qb3tn850tadctgku&workoutRow%3A0%3Amark=on&workoutRow%3A0%3Asport=8&reviewSumbit=1' --compressed
```

I guess there should be a cleaner way to do this, but I don't know where to start.

Thanks for reading, feel free to ask more details.

Have a great day.

François